# Multiple table JOIN issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join

first, you should know that i suck big time at SQL.

Here is my problem:

I have 4 tables that i need to be joinned (for usage in SphinxSearch), here is the rough structure:

### Accounts

```
Id Name Category
----------------
1  Test 1
2  Foo  2
3  Bar  1
```

### Category

```
Id Name
-------
1  Restaurants
2  Store
```

### Accounts_has_subcategory

```
account_id subcat_id
--------------------
1          1
1          3
2          2
```

### Subcategory

```
Id Name
-------
1  Chinese
2  Sportswear
3  Delivery
```

What i want is a resultset looking like this:

```
accounts.id | accounts.name | category_name | subcategories
-----------------------------------------------------------
1             Test            Restaurants     Chinese, Delivery
2             Foo             Store           Sportswear
```

Right my query looks like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, c.name as category, group_concat(subcat.name) as subcategories
FROM accounts AS a
JOIN (account_has_subcategory AS ahs, subcategory AS subcat)
ON (a.id = ahs.account_id AND ahs.subcat_id = subcat.id),
accounts AS a2
JOIN category AS c
ON a2.category = c.id
```

Like said before, i suck at SQL (as soon as it involves multiple joins or stuff like that basically...). If someone could point me in the right direction or offer a solution (with basic explanation, so i can try and get that in my brain -_-), that would make my day since i've been fighting that query for a good 5h now...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, 
       c.name as category, 
       group_concat(subcat.name) as subcategories
FROM accounts AS a
INNER JOIN account_has_subcategory AS ahs ON a.id = ahs.account_id
INNER JOIN subcategory AS subcat ON subcat.id = ahs.subcat_id
INNER JOIN category AS c ON a.category = c.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, c.name
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. (Have to wait 7min to approve your answer)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there - you just need to fix up your syntax a little and add a group by.

```
select a.id, a.name, c.name as category, group_concat(subcat.name) as subcategories
from accounts as a
inner join category as c on a.category = c.id
inner join accounts_has_subcategory as ahs on a.id = ahs.account_id
inner join subcategory as subcat on ahs.subcat_id = subcat.id
group by a.id, a.name, c.name
```